# Does storage affect file caching in cp?

Tags: cache, storage, cp, io

I read somewhere that `cp` uses file caching, but why does coping something the size of ~100MB result in a file cache of more than 100MB in ram? Does this also change if copying from HDD -> HDD,SSD -> SSD,HDD -> SSD, and maybe another storage medium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since source disk is buffered and destination disk is also buffered, it is normal that peak buffer usage exceeds the file size.  If you use `mv` then source disk cache should be dropped immediately after file deletion.

Storage type would not affect disk cache much, the file system you choose will.